# Undertow ReceiverTestCase hang forever

Tags: java, wildfly, undertow

I cloned the Undertow repo from GitHub like described here:
http://undertow.io/undertow-docs/undertow-docs-1.3.0/index.html#undertow-faq 
After that I did a mvn install.
Every thing works until the ReceiverTestCase is executed. After that the mvn install process hang forever. And only by interrupting from the console it ends.

Comment: If you are using osx/linux have you considered using dtruss / strace  to diagnose what mvn is doing?

Comment: no i'm running on windows